# Adding Column value(Days_Spent), to a datetime day value in column Est_end

Tags: python, function, datetime, addition, timedelta

```
df=pd.read_csv("C:Tasks_Revised_For_Analysis.csv")
print df['Days_Spent']
Out[16]: 
0                       5.0
1        43.333333333333336
2        176.66666666666666
3                      80.5
4                      78.5
5        0.3333333333333333

print df['Start_Date']
Out[17]:
0           2015-10-29
1           2016-01-07 
2           2015-10-29
3           2015-10-29 
4           2015-11-01
5           2015-11-02
```

Days_Spent is a float of a calculated value

```
df['Days_Spent'] = (df['ActualHours'] / 6.00)
```

This is my best guess as to what I should do

```
g = (df['Days_Spent'])

df['Est_end'] = df['Start_Date'] + datetime.timedelta(days = g)
```

This is the error I am receiving even tho I have datetime and timedelta imported
    type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: If the data are confidential, maybe you could come up with some dummy data

Comment: I have created some and added it, thank you

Comment: aren't you assigning a series to g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df['Est_end'] = df['Start_Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Days_Spent'], unit='D')
```

Take into accout that `unit='D'` implies that 8.5 will be interpreted as "8 and a half days", or "8 days and 12 hours". You might want to round up or down the numbers first.

See more in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! Thank you so much!